# Why do I continually get an error using a php api script?

Tags: php

I am trying to add an api to my site that allows users to subscribe to a mailchimp list. For some reason I keep getting an error and I just can't figure out what is wrong. ( I'm using php 7 and seem to have Curl installed on the server).

The Error

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in subscribe.php on line 10
```

Subscribe.php

```
<?php

    $email = 'email address';
    $list_id = 'list id';
    $api_key = 'api key';

    $data_center = substr($api_key,strpos($api_key,'-')+1);

    $url = 'https://'. $data_center .'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'. $list_id .'/members';

    $json = json_encode([
        'email_address' => $email,
        'status'        => 'subscribed', //pass 'subscribed' or 'pending'
    ]);

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $api_key);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $status_code;
    ?>
```

Comment: double check with phpinfo() your version

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php suggests short array syntax from php 5.4

Comment: I'm wrong, I have a php version 5.2.17 installed and curl is enabled (libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2).

Comment: @JulianJ Use array() syntax in that case, [] isn't supported in 5.2 (your new code would be `$json = json_encode(array(
        'email_address' => $email,
        'status'        => 'subscribed', //pass 'subscribed' or 'pending'
    ));`

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Comment: or, even better, upgrade to a version of php which isn't approaching 8 years unsupported http://php.net/eol.php

Comment: @JulianJ - for heavens sake! Upgrade your PHP version immediately! Please don't let any server running PHP 5.2 anywhere near the public internet. There are a whole load of major security flaws in versions that old that simply haven't been fixed. The current version of PHP is 7.2, with 7.3 due out in December. The oldest version currently supported is 5.6, but that will drop out of support when 7.3 is released.

Comment: Point taken, I'm on it now. For some reason I always I thought I had php 7. Thanks for the heads up.